# Can I write a this function inside $scope function in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Is it possible to  write a function like this?

```
$scope.myFunc = function () {
    this.details = 1;
    this.setDetails = function (d) {
        this.details = d;
    }

}
```

How can I call this function from view?

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" ng-click="myFunc.setDetails('hi')">set Details</a>
```

It is not even calling my function.

Comment: @Tushar it was a typing mistake.. I edited the question. please check now

Comment: Add `return this;` from `myFunc` and then call it as `ng-click="myFunc().setDetails('hi')"`

Comment: How do you use `details` then?

Comment: @Tushar it is now calling the first function, but not enetering into the this.setDetails(d)

Comment: Use 2-way data binding, Use `$scope.details = 1`. And access it in view as `{{details}}`

Comment: You don't really understand what `this` in such cases is. So one more time, explain how you expect to use `details` in HTML, then we can suggest you good solution.

Comment: Controller: `$scope.details = 1;
$scope.setDetails = function (d) {
    $scope.details = d;
};`

HTML: `<a href="javascript:void(0)" ng-click="setDetails('hi')">{{details}}</a>` @dfsq Is that to me or OP

Comment: @Tushar It was for OP. But nevermind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I prepare working example for you. First use constructor function and then create new instance `$scope.myfunc` by calling `new MyFunc()`.

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);


myApp.controller('myController', function($scope) {   
   
    //Constructor function
    function MyFunc () {      
     this.details = 1;
 this.setDetails = function(details) {
        this.details = details;
     }
    }
    //New instance of MyFunc
    $scope.myfunc = new MyFunc();  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp">
    <div ng-controller="myController">
        <input type="text" ng-model="myfunc.details">
        <button ng-click="myfunc.setDetails('hi')">Click me</button>
        
    </div>
</div>
```